# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Asp.Net Core + Angular 10

Tags: asp.net, angular, http, asp.net-core

I'm following a tutorial using Asp.net plus angular server using CORS package. Basically I'm trying to execute a post request:

```
 // POST: api/Trackers
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Tracker>> PostTracker(Tracker tracker)
        {
            _context.Tracker.Add(tracker);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetTracker", new { id = tracker.entryId }, tracker);
        }
```

using this service on Angular Front-End:

```
export class TrackerDetailService {
  formData: TrackerDetail
  readonly rootURL = "http://localhost:55354/api"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postTracker(formData:TrackerDetail) {
      return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/Trackers' , formData);
  }
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

[image]

I'm quite inexperienced at troubleshooting HTTP errors so any help would be appreciated.

Update: I've been losing my sleep over this for the past 3 days. I've tried a different Angular+.Net Tutorial and I'm getting stuck at the same point, not being able to send data from the front-end. :( Help!

Comment: can you post your `Program` and `Startup` classes (or better still a *minimal* working repo on github)? Do you run this in Docker?

Comment: If it's a  cors error, you should have other errors in the console. Do you have anything else?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostTracker(Tracker tracker)
    {
        _context.Tracker.Add(tracker);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(Tracker)
    }
```

or this

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostTracker(Tracker tracker)
    {
        _context.Tracker.Add(tracker);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetTracker", new { id = tracker.entryId }, tracker);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for replying. The problem is that I'm using parallels to run windows on my mac and I was trying to access the endpoints based on windows from the view on Mac. It was never going to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed CORS on your Startup.cs ? Show your Startup.cs file. It should be like this.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       // create cors policy
        services.AddCors(options =>
            options.AddPolicy("DefaultCorsPolicy", builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod())
        );
        services.AddControllers();
    }


     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
     {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(); //must be placed after UseRouting , but before UseAuthorization
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
      }


       //USAGE:
       [EnableCors("DefaultCorsPolicy")]
       [Route("api/tracker")]
       public class TrackerController : ControllerBase
       {
          [HttpGet]
          public string Get() => "API controller is running";
       }
```